# Unable to use webrtc in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc

I am trying to use webrtc in my react native app but whenever i install my app , it closes automatically this starts happening after I installed the react-native-webrtc package in my app ,before that my app was working
here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "demoApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.1",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.75.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.2.6",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.2.7",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I even tried 1.75.1 and 1.75.0 version of react-native-webrtc but still Same Issue

Answer (score 0):

After install react-native-webrtc package,

you have to follow [this guide](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc#installation).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this in your gradle.properties:
`android.enableDexingArtifactTransform.desugaring=false`

and enjoy!